# can't debug small program on eclipse helios cdt using mingw/gdb under windows, console freezes

Tags: c++, windows-xp, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I've been trying to use Eclipse CDT to do some c++ examples, i can run them just fine with the run command, but whenever i try to Debug, the console window freezes up, I'm able to input, but the program doesn't continue.

When I debug, i get the following output on the console window (no breakpoints, but breaks on main because of default settings):

```
Hello, world
put your name: 15^running
```

The continue button is disabled and doesn't do anything when I input something and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>. The 15 is a random number, sometimes its 16, 20 etc.

If I run the program under eclipse I get the input prompt just fine:

```
Hello, world
put your name: test
Hello test
```

this is the code I try to debug:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, world" << std::endl;
    std::string name;
    std::cout << "put your name: ";
    std::cin >> name;
    std::cout << "Hello " + name << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My path var:
`C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WBEM;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_14\bin;C:\MinGW\bin`

Eclipse version: Helios Service Release 2
CDT version: 7.0.2
OS: windows xp
GDB version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.2

How can I debug this small example under CDT, without issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following is from the Eclipse website's FAQ:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#Eclipse_console_does_not_show_output_on_Windows

> Eclipse console does not show output on Windows In Eclipse CDT on
>   Windows, standard output of the program being run or debugged is fully
>   buffered, because it is not connected to a Windwos console, but to a
>   pipe. See bug 173732 for more details. Either add fflush calls after
>   every printf or add the following lines in the start of the main
>   function:

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

Seems like an expected bug on windows.

Answer (score 12):

`15^running` looks as a result record from gdb's [Machine Interface](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/GDB_002fMI.html#GDB_002fMI). Normally it shouldn't appear in the Eclipse console.

I recommend trying a different Create Process Launcher. It can be changed in the following way:

1. In Main menu choose "Run" -> "Debug Configurations...".
2. In the opened "Debug Configurations" window shown below click "Select other..." opposite "Using GDB (DSF) Create Process Launcher".

   [image]
3. In the opened "Select Preferred Launcher" window shown below check "Use configuration specific settings", select "Standard Create Process Launcher" in the list below and click OK.

   [image]
4. Now go to the Debugger tab in the "Debug Configurations" window, select debugger, e.g. "MinGW gdb" and click Apply.

   [image]

With the Standard Create Process Launcher I am able to debug your program although "put your name:" is printed only after I type something and hit Enter, because the output stream is not flushed.

Comment: Thanks for this - this was the problem I was having on linux as well, when trying to debug mozilla using gdb + eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Try having a look at this http://www.cprogramming.com/gdbtutorial.html and see if that helps. Like can you press CTRL-C to break?

Also [Cannot enter input with gdb. Help!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645394/cannot-enter-input-with-gdb-help) might be a pointer although related to apple.

Comment: I got a little further now, i think its a problem with the windows console not popping up. i'm looking at codelite right now, seems to perform a bit better at debugging.