# c++ debug mode in eclipse causes program to not wait for cin

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse-cdt

The following code works fine when it's run but there's an issue when it's run in debug mode using Eclipse, it does not wait for input and instead just keeps going and some seemingly random value is printed to the console. It also won't stop at a breakpoint.

```
int main() {

        int N, Q, maxSize;
        cout <<"Enter a number"<<endl;
        int test;
        cin >> test;
        cout << test <<endl;
    }
```

Comment: what is the output its prints on the eclipse console?

Comment: we need the eclipse version too...

Comment: I ran it just now and it printed 62. closed eclipse and restarted and it printed 52, then ran it again and it printed 50

Eclipse version info:

Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers

Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)

Comment: What is the OS ? Are you on Windows ?

Comment: yes, on Windows 10

Comment: This question will probably help https://stackoverflow.com/q/6004610/72178.

Comment: Appreciate the help but no luck with that link. Just going to use VS for now but if anyone figures this out I'd really appreciate it (normally I'd prefer to work in Eclipse).

Comment: Although I haven't used VS for a while, AFAIK VS does a similar thing as my suggested answer, i.e. it opens up a separate console window

Answer (score 10):

**Update**

From CDT 9.4 (Eclipse Oxygen.2) there is now a checkbox in the launch configuration to do this with one-click. See https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/NewIn94#Debug

[image]

---

**Original answer**

The problem here is there are two readers on the same stdin channel. When you do `cin` Eclipse CDT is also trying to read stdin for the GDB-MI communication.

Fortunately there is a workaround, you can have GDB create a separate console for the program that is running. That means no sharing of the handles.

To do so create a `.gdbinit` file in the root of the project with these contents:

```
set new-console on
```

and debug your console app in Eclipse to your heart's content:
[image: example]

**More Info**

You can set the gdbinit file to use for your Debug Configuration in the *Debugger* tab. Set the *GDB Command file* to the name of the file you have created.
[image: debugger tab]

You can set the default *GDB Command file* to use for newly created Debug Configurations by editing the preference in *C/C++* -> *Debug* -> *GDB* page:
[image: GDB page]

Eclipse CDT does not use the .gdbinit in your home directory. This is on purpose because the .gdbinit that is there is normally set up for CLI debugging and can easily interfere with the MI inteface needed for Eclipse to communicate with GDB properly.

Comment: Did the external windows console come up, like in my screenshot?

Comment: Since I wrote this answer, with CDT 9.4 and above, there is a checkbox to press. See https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/NewIn94#Debug

Comment: To open `Debug Configuration`, click `Run > Debug Configuration`